# Bash: Bad subtitution error in a for loop - git tags

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to execute a migration from SVN to GIT using `git svn clone ..` and everything works smoothly.

Now i need to transform the tags in SVN to real tags in git using this command

```
for t in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin/tags) 
do 
    git tag ${t/origin\/tags\//} $t - #BAD substitution error - need to fix
    git branch -D -r $t
done
```

If i run this script in my commandline it works, but if i run this script in a shell script it will fail with a "Bad substitution error" . Any advice here?

The full script is here:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## Modificed script - Fork from https://github.com/MPDFT/svn-to-git

####### Project name
PROJECT_NAME="" #Example - Digisharp
SVN_USERNAME="" #Example - adys
GIT_USERNAME="" #Example - adys
GIT_CREDENTIAL="" #Example - pz2fekhjcsq5io5xbslcuss5lspo4lcgh4cwjswge265uzxrnzxv

####### SVN
# SVN repository to be migrated
SVN_URL="" #Example - 

####### GIT
# Git repository to migrate - IMPORTANT! YOU MUST INCLUDE YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD(PAT TOKEN FOR AZURE) 
# We need this to automate the git push without having it asking you for password
GIT_URL="" #Example - 

###########################
#### Don't need to change from here
###########################

#STYLE_COLOR
RED='\033[0;31m'
LIGHT_GREEN='\e[1;32m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color


echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [LOG] Starting migration of ${NC}" $SVN_TRUNK
echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [LOG] Using: ${NC}" $(git --version)
echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [LOG] Using: ${NC}"  $(svn --version | grep svn,)
echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [LOG] Step 01/05 Create Directories ${NC}"
echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [RUN] Step 02/05 ${NC} £ git svn clone --stdlayout --no-minimize-url $BASE_SVN $PROJECT_NAME --user=$SVN_USERNAME"
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-minimize-url $SVN_URL $PROJECT_NAME --user=$SVN_USERNAME --authors-file=authors.txt
cd $PROJECT_NAME
echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [RUN] Step 03/05 ${NC} $ git remote add origin"
git remote add origin $GIT_URL
echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [RUN] Step 04/05 ${NC} - Preparing the git branches and tags"
for t in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/origin/tags) 
do 
    #git tag ${t/origin\/tags\//} $t - BAD substitution error - need to fix
    git branch -D -r $t
done

for b in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes)
do 
    git branch $b refs/remotes/$b
    git branch -D -r $b
done
echo -e "${LIGHT_GREEN} [RUN] Step 05/05 [RUN] git push ${NC}"
git push origin --all
git push origin --tags
echo "Successful - The git repository is now available in" $GIT_URL
```

I run the command with `sh migration.sh`

Comment: Different shells?

Comment: Check my edit. Iam running the command in a bash shell

Comment: By different shells I mean that the shell you use to run the script (`#!/bin/bash`) could be different that the interactive shell you used to test the command. Even different versions of Bash matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you executing your script with something like `/bin/sh /path/to/script.sh`?

`${t/origin\/tags\//}` is available in bash but isn't POSIX shell compatible, you might have success chancing it to something like:

```
echo "$t" | sed 's~origin/tags/~~'
```

I would highly recommend linting your script with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), as you got a few potential errors.

Answer (score 0):

> I run the command with `sh migration.sh`.

`${var/search/replacement}` is a bash feature. Running `sh` explicitly means the `#!/bin/bash` shebang line is ignored. Never run scripts that way.

There's no need to edit the script to remove the bashisms. Just run it with `./migration.sh` so the shebang is respected.

```
$ ./migration.sh
```